# Neutrino and Express Preset

Tags: express, webpack, neutrino

I'm using Neutrino as scaffolding tool for Webpack 3.1 and I'm looking for a proper Neutrino preset that combines Express and Webpack so that I see a 'Hello World' website. If someone gives me one proper preset and tells me how to install it, I'll accept this as an answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should already be possible with the [@neutrinojs/node](https://neutrino.js.org/packages/node/) preset:

```
// src/index.js

import express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Thank you. when i install the @neutrinojs/node preset, I get a totally different index.js:


import { createServer } from 'http';
import app from './app';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

createServer((request, response) => response.end(app()))
  .listen(port, () => process.stdout.write(`Running on :${port}\n`));

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./app');
}

and when I replace the content of it with your post's content, i get:

Server running on port 3000
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/blabla/neutrino_tutorial_5/build/index.html'

Comment: So, how can I tell Neutrino to build my src/webapp.js (in which my frontend-code is located Jquery etc.) as index.html into the build-folder?

Comment: You may be better off posting a reduced test case repository for me to look at.